# calculate diff() in python on subsets of data within a dataframe

Tags: python, multiple-columns, timedelta

I am new to Python and coming from SAS.  I want to calculate a lag variable (time difference using diff()) between sequential rows, but I want to re-start the process every time I encounter a new individual.  In SAS this is done using dif() or lag() using a by-command.  Is there a similar way to do this using Python?

Here is what I want the data to look like (note the missing data each time I encounter a new value for PIT):

```
PIT Receiver    tottime     Lag
1   1   2015-01-21 12:00:00 
1   1   2015-01-21 12:00:05 5
1   1   2015-01-21 12:00:20 15
1   1   2015-01-21 12:00:30 10
1   1   2015-01-21 12:00:35 5
1   2   2015-01-22 12:00:35 86400
1   2   2015-01-22 12:00:50 15
1   2   2015-01-22 12:00:55 5
1   2   2015-01-22 12:01:05 10
1   2   2015-01-22 12:01:10 5
2   1   2015-01-12 12:01:10 
2   1   2015-01-12 12:01:15 5
2   2   2015-01-12 12:01:20 5
2   2   2015-01-12 12:01:25 5
2   2   2015-01-12 12:01:30 5
```

I tried this using this code:

```
Clean['tottime']=pd.to_datetime(Clean.tottime.values)   #Convert tottime to     datetime value
tindex=Clean.tottime.values                             #Create vector of time values that will become part of a multi-index
arrays = [Clean.PIT.values,tIndex]                      # Define arrays object, which contains both levels of the multi-index

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names = ['PIT','tottime'])                # declare multi level index
Clean.index = index

Clean['lag'] = Clean.tottime.diff()                                     #    calculated difference in tottime between rows
Clean['lag'] = Clean['lag']/np.timedelta64(1,'s')                       #This converts 'lag' to a numeric (float64) value
```

But this produces something like this (i.e. works on first row, but then does not recognize the new PIT value):

```
PIT Receiver    tottime    Lag
1   1   2015-01-21 12:00:00 
1   1   2015-01-21 12:00:05 5
1   1   2015-01-21 12:00:20 15
1   1   2015-01-21 12:00:30 10
1   1   2015-01-21 12:00:35 5
1   2   2015-01-22 12:00:35 86400
1   2   2015-01-22 12:00:50 15
1   2   2015-01-22 12:00:55 5
1   2   2015-01-22 12:01:05 10
1   2   2015-01-22 12:01:10 5
2   1   2015-01-12 12:01:10 -864000
2   1   2015-01-12 12:01:15 5
2   2   2015-01-12 12:01:20 5
2   2   2015-01-12 12:01:25 5
2   2   2015-01-12 12:01:30 5
```

So it is failing to reset on the new PIT, and I get a big negative number (10 days previous).  Eventually I want to be able to do this on PIT and Receiver., but for now the challenge is to iterate this process over tottime, grouped by PIT.  Any suggestions for how to do this?

Also I suspect this is a subset of a common problem (by-processing), but I do not know how to phrase the question in Python-speak, so am not finding them on the StackOverflow site.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the pandas `groupby()` functionality.

This is a slightly cumbersome approach as I don't have your code, but you could try the following, assuming that your DataFrame is in the same format as you have shown, without the `lag` column.

First, create a function, `diff_func`, which will be applied to the groupby object.

```
def diff_func(df):
    return df.diff()
```

Then use the `groupby()`:

```
Clean['Lag'] = Clean.groupby('PIT')['tottime'].apply(diff_func)
```

The above line basically groups `Clean` by the column `PIT`, tells pandas to apply the function to the column `tottime` and then dumps it in the new column `Lag`.

Comment: Perfecto!  So to clarify in your example, you said to create a function f, but did you df?  it seems that df is what gets called, but that is probably just my poor understanding.  Note that I did have to convert tottime to an index (I did PIT and tottime as multiindex), but the diff function works now, and leaves the gaps where I want them.  So the next question is if I wanted to add Receiver to the multiindex can I do that, or will I have to merge PIT and Receiver into a single column?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I changed name of the function in the code at the last minute, but forgot to update the text. `diff_func` is the function that gets called, and `df` is the argument representing a DataFrame that gets passed.

Comment: Regarding adding receiver to the MultiIndex - I don't see why not.

Comment: Yep, worked like a charm.  Here's what the working code looks like:     Clean['Lag'] = Clean.groupby(['PIT','Receiver'])['tottime'].apply(diff_func) ...and naturally I had to add "...,'Receiver', " to the index line above

Answer (score 0):

so you're saying whenever you have a differing `PIT` from the previous row? that's easy:

```
df.loc[df.PIT != df.PIT.shift(1), 'Lag'] = 0
```

Comment: Good idea--I was thinking of something along these lines as well, although I would prefer it to be nan (or naT), since the next step will be to perform analyses and transformations (and zeros should not happen)

Comment: in that case, you would just use `= np.nan`